# Fill a grid with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds, grids

How do I fill a grid in TikZ? I want to do something like:

```
\draw[draw,fill=red!20] (0,0) grid (2,2);
```

instead of manually drawing 4 rectangles.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately not a direct solution, but you can just append a `rectangle` operation going back to the origin of the grid:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [ultra thick, draw=black, fill=black!20!white] (0,0) grid  (2,2) rectangle (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: filled grid tikz]

Comment: In this case you can have some problem. The rectangle is drawn, the line width is the same for the grid and the rectangle.

Comment: @Altermundus: That's correct, but it's not a very problematic behaviour.

Comment: What a beautiful solution! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

I think no but perhaps I am wrong. One rectangle is enough:

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[red!20](0,0) rectangle (2,2); 
  \draw (0,0) grid (2,2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 0):

With PSTricks. Unfortunately PSTricks' grid has no options for changing

- the fill color
- the line style

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\addtopsstyle{gridstyle}{griddots=0}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](4,4)
    \psframe*[linecolor=gray](4,4)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```