# Drawing a multicolored grid using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw a grid similar to the one below in the question answer?

[Fill a grid with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21066/fill-a-grid-with-tikz)

But I can select different fill colors for the separate cells?

I need to be able to color (fill) in the separate nodes in the grid. I tried using this, but for some reasons there's some weird padding on the fill

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\title{Title} 
\author{User} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[step=0.5cm,color=black] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
    \node[fill=green] at (-0.75,+0.75) {};
    \node at (-0.25,+0.75) {};
    \node at (+0.25,+0.75) {};
    \node at (+0.75,+0.75) {};
    \node at (-0.75,+0.25) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Sorry about that, I included the necessary preambles and code now

Comment: Perhaps [this helps](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59055/fill-nodes-according-to-table-data-file/59759#59759)?

Comment: possible duplicate http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271577/how-can-i-fill-the-grid-cell-with-color-in-this-grid

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={minimum size=.5cm-\pgflinewidth, outer sep=0pt}]
    \draw[step=0.5cm,color=black] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
    \node[fill=green] at (-0.75,+0.75) {};
    \node[fill=red] at (-0.25,+0.75) {};
    \node[fill=orange] at (+0.25,+0.75) {};
    \node[fill=yellow] at (+0.75,+0.75) {};
    \node[fill=purple!70] at (-0.75,+0.25) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Update:

Command `\draw[step=0.5cm,color=black] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);` draws the grid. `step` fixes element size and coordinates before and after `grid` define grid dimensions. If you want a grid with three rows and eight columns with 0.5cm squares and bottom left corner at `(0,0)`, use

```
\draw[step=0.5cm,color=black] (0,0) grid (4,1.5);
```

as in

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={minimum size=.5cm-\pgflinewidth, outer sep=0pt}]
    \draw[step=0.5cm,color=black] (0,0) grid (6,1.5);
    \node[fill=green] at (0.25,+1.25) {};
    \node[fill=red] at (0.25,+0.25) {};
    \node[fill=orange] at (+3.25,+0.75) {};
    \node[fill=orange] at (+2.75,+0.75) {};
    \node[fill=yellow] at (+5.75,+1.25) {};
    \node[fill=purple!70] at (5.75,+0.25) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, this is exactly what I'm looking for, but how can I change the dimensions of the grid? (i.e. to 3 by n)

Comment: @PhilipTsang Answer updated.

Comment: Is it possible to write text inside the colored rectangles?

Comment: @alper Yes, just write whatever you want into `{}` of desired node. But remember that nodes adapt their size to the contents, then it's possible that you break this structure if the text is larger than available space.

Answer (score 9):

You can use a matrix :

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[fill=orange]
    \matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw,minimum size=1cm}, nodes in empty cells,column sep=-\pgflinewidth,row sep=-\pgflinewidth](M){
               &          &   |[fill]|   &   |[fill]|   &   |[fill]|   &   |[fill]|   &          &          \\
               & |[fill]| &              &              &              &              & |[fill]| &          \\
      |[fill]| &          &   |[fill]|   &              &   |[fill]|   &              &          & |[fill]| \\
      |[fill]| &          &   |[fill]|   &              &   |[fill]|   &              &          & |[fill]| \\
      |[fill]| &          &              &              &              & |[fill=red]| &          & |[fill]| \\
      |[fill]| &          & |[fill=red]| & |[fill=red]| & |[fill=red]| &              &          & |[fill]| \\
               & |[fill]| &              &              &              &              & |[fill]| &          \\
               &          & |[fill]|     & |[fill]|     & |[fill]|     & |[fill]|     &          &          \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  pics/square/.default={1},
  pics/square/.style = {
    code = {
    \draw[pic actions] (0,0) rectangle (#1,#1);
    }
  }
}    

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \foreach \x in {1,2,...,10}  {
     \foreach \y in {1,2,...,5} {
       \pic[fill=blue!50] at (\x,\y) {square};
     }
   }
   \pic[fill=yellow] at (5,3) {square};
   \pic[draw=none,fill=yellow] at (1.25,2.25) {square=.5};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\foreach` combined with `/.try` key handler to apply style to some cells :

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[fill=orange,
    cell27/.style={fill}, cell37/.style={fill}, cell47/.style={fill}, cell57/.style={fill},
    cell16/.style={fill}, cell66/.style={fill},
    cell05/.style={fill}, cell25/.style={fill}, cell45/.style={fill}, cell75/.style={fill},
    cell04/.style={fill}, cell24/.style={fill}, cell44/.style={fill}, cell74/.style={fill},
    cell03/.style={fill}, cell53/.style={fill=red}, cell73/.style={fill},
    cell02/.style={fill}, cell22/.style={fill=red}, cell32/.style={fill=red}, cell42/.style={fill=red}, cell72/.style={fill},
    cell11/.style={fill}, cell61/.style={fill},
    cell20/.style={fill}, cell30/.style={fill}, cell40/.style={fill}, cell50/.style={fill},
  ]
    \foreach \i in {0,...,7}
      \foreach \j in {0,...,7}
        \path[cell\i\j/.try] (\i,\j) rectangle +(1,1);
    \draw grid (8,8);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]